# why parsing xml file in swift 4 will return incomplete?

Tags: ios, xml, uitableview, swift4, parsexml

so here is the codes that I used for parsing xml and the texts that I received in the print and the table view were incomplete

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    let data = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

    print(data)
    if data.count != 0 {
        switch termsItem {

        case "title" : termsTitle = data
        case "body" : termsTexts = data
            default :
            break


        }


    }
}
```

and I change this code to this below and now the print of the xml is correct But I can't see any thing in the table view

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    let data = string

    print(data)
    if data.count != 0 {
        switch termsItem {

        case "title" : termsTitle = data
        case "body" : termsTexts = data
            default :
            break


        }


    }
}
```

here is the other codes But I didn't changed them

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {


    termsItem = elementName

}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {


    if elementName == "item" {

        var theItems = Item()
        theItems.title = termsTitle
        theItems.body = termsTexts
        print(theItems)
        print(theItems.title)
        print(termsTitle)
        tableViewterms.append(theItems)

    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.otherTopicsTableView.reloadData()



    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I had to append the data and then remove them now this code is working well

```
 func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {

    termsItem = elementName

}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    let data = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

    if data.count != 0 {
        switch termsItem {

        case "title" : termsTitle = data
        case "body" : termsTexts.append(contentsOf: data)
            default :
            break

        }
    }
}


func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {


    if elementName == "item" {

        var theItems = Item()
        theItems.title = termsTitle
        theItems.body = termsTexts
        print(theItems.body)
        termsTexts.removeAll()
        tableViewterms.append(theItems)

    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.otherTopicsTableView.reloadData()

    }

}
```